# help required with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-intent, android-service

Basically, my problem is that i need to send data from my service (started with Intent) to my main activity. (this is my first attempt at using a BroadcastReceiver)

I have two apps, com.example.myapp (contains main activity) and com.example.myapp.licence (contains background service)

What i currently have is as follows:

com.example.myapp > MainActivity:

```
// Start background service
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.example.myapp.licence", "com.example.myapp.licence.LicenceCheck");
startService(intent);

// Setup BroadcastReceiver 
private BroadcastReceiver MyBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String status = extras.getString("status");
    }
};

//  Start reciever
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("STATUS_RETURN");
registerReceiver(MyBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

com.example.myapp.licence > LicenceCheck:

```
Intent intentToActivity = new Intent("STATUS_RETURN");
intent.putExtra("status", "verified");
sendBroadcast(intentToActivity);
```

can anyone please suggest what i need to change to get this BroadcastReceiver to work?

**EDIT**:
Edited to correct a typo ..problem still exists

**EDIT 2**:
It now seems now that the BroadcastReciever is being used, but theres a problem with the following line (as it force closes on it):

```
String status = extras.getString("status");
```

**EDIT 3**:
Above problem fixed by surrounding that line with the following IF statment:

```
if (extras != null)
```

but "extras" seems to always be null, anyone know why?

Comment: where do you register the receiver?

Comment: Is your service successfully started?

Comment: is that these two lines:  `code`IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("STATUS_RETURN");
   registerReceiver(MyBroadcastReceiver, filter); `code`??  if so, i have that inside a function (if thats what their called in java) which is called onStart() of my MainActivity

Comment: and yes, my service does successfully start (i know this as my service saves a file)

Comment: Seems you are passing the wrong pparameter to setclass method. Check my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess mismatched "STATUS_REUTRN" and "STATUS_RETURN" have something to do with it?

**Update**

It seem that you have problems with [Intent resolution](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) (scroll down a screen). Intent can be one of:

- **Explicit intent** - must have target class defined via `setClass()`.
- **Implicit intent** - must have enough info included to be resolved: type, action, category.

So if possible, add this to your broadcast intent:

```
intentToActivity.setClassx(this, com.example.myapp.MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: oh, that was silly of me xD   thanks for pointing out that error, but its still not working ):

Comment: Also, you use `intentToActivity = new ..` and on line later `intent.putExtra("status", "verified")`. Typo?

Comment: i get an error when trying to use getClass() which suggests to replace it with getClassName(),  which doesnt fix the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Change the visibility of the broadcast receiver to `public`.

start your service like

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.myapp.licence.LicenceCheck.class));
```

Comment: yeah, still the problem persists

Comment: You try passing the context instead of the package name in setclass().

Answer (score 0):

I use AIDL to achieve this.
It allows a way to transfer data between your service and activity.
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html

It's a lot to learn but that's the best way I know of to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

After ages of testing, I've finally found the problem.

I was adding the string in the service to the wrong Intent;
adding it accidently to a previously defined one, rather than the one sending a broadcast.

Original:
    intent.putExtra("status", "verified") ;

Correct:
    intentToActivity.putExtra("status", "verified");

Thanks again for all the help everyone

Comment: You ignored `Peter Knego`'s comments. He had pointed that out 13hrs ago.

Comment: Oh  D:   I never ignored it, I didn't understand what the comment was pointing out at first  :/   I'll mark his as the correct answer